# Does this sentence use parallel structure?

Tags: parallelism

Does the following sentence make use of parallel structure:

"Thus, Soyster’s diction most definitely exemplifies how he views himself in a dreary and pitiful manner and Mairs’s diction, contrariwise to Soyster’s, exemplifies how she views herself in a pleasant and benign manner."

If not, could you tell me how I can make it have parallel structure. I am very bad with English, and more mathematically inclined, so please break things down.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you *want* this complex sentence to make use of parallel structure? Are you sure you know what [parallel structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) actually means? From that Wikipedia link - Parallel: *She likes to cook, jog, and **read**,* or *She likes cooking, jogging, and **reading**.* Non-parallel: *She likes cooking, jogging, and **to read**.*

Comment: The question isn't why; I just need to know whether it uses parallel structure. The reason for my doubts is the "contrariwise to Soyster's" part.

Comment: It just means opposite to Soyster's diction.

Comment: I know what it means, but does that subordinate clause corrupt the eminent parallel structure?

Comment: You might like to consider the final example in my Wikipedia link: *"We have petitioned and our petitions have been scorned. We have entreated and our entreaties have been disregarded. We have begged and they have mocked **when our calamity came**.* The fact that the last element there includes an extra (highlighted) component doesn't mean the structures are "not parallel". Essentially, the element ***We did this and that was the response*** is repeated three times.

Comment: ...it's really the same in your example, where the "non-repeated" elements *most definitely* and *contrariwise to Soyster’s* don't affect the "parallel structure". If you want to call it that.

Comment: @user62726: Bear in mind that it wouldn't really be very "natural" for the third sentence in that last example to be rephrased as * We have begged and **our begging has been ignored***. But strictly speaking, it would be grammatical, and I suppose you'd have to say it would be "more parallel".

Comment: You can't **corrupt** a structure; you can vary it, and it's done all the time. Unless you have some definition of "eminent parallel structure" that specifies every possible variation in advance, you'd better allow normal syntactic and pragmatic processes to happen. Otherwise I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the structure here is strongly parallel. The words don't have to match exactly.

"Soyster's diction exemplifies ... how he views himself in a dreary and pitiful manner"

is parallel to:

"Mairs's diction exemplifies ... how she views herself in a pleasant and benign manner".

An example of a non-parallel version might be:

"Soyster's diction exemplifies how he views himself in a dreary and pitiful manner, while Mairs's diction indicates a pleasant and benign self-image."